# Supervisord sending SIGKILL for an asyncio (python) task after 2 minutes

Tags: python, python-asyncio, supervisord

I have an api built using Quart and asyncio in python. An endpoint generates a background task which would run for 5 minutes atleast but Supervisord send SIGKILL command for that task and terminates it midway.

I don't see any reason why supervisord would kill it.

Log :

```
2020-05-06 09:37:53,791 INFO supervisord started with pid 9
2020-05-06 09:37:54,794 INFO spawned: 'web-app' with pid 12
2020-05-06 09:37:54,795 INFO spawned: 'push-service' with pid 13
2020-05-06 09:37:55,797 INFO success: web-app entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2020-05-06 09:38:11,614 INFO success: push-service entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 16 seconds (startsecs)
2020-05-06 09:46:48,389 INFO exited: web-app (terminated by SIGKILL; not expected)
2020-05-06 09:46:49,393 INFO spawned: 'web-app' with pid 63
2020-05-06 09:46:50,394 INFO success: web-app entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task was memory heavy and container didn't have enough memory so the task was getting killed halfway.

Adding more memory to container resolved the issue.