# Gunicorn worker reboots abruptly without any errors

Tags: python, gunicorn, aiohttp

I'm facing an issue with the gunicorn worker that it reboots automatically. I have enabled the debug logs as well but there were no error logs on the gunicorn worker but it rebooted abruptly.

The gunicorn config I have is,

```
gunicorn \
-c gunicorn_config.py \
-b 0.0.0.0:5000 aiohttp_wsgi_handler:aioapp \
-k aiohttp.worker.GunicornWebWorker \
-w 3 \
--access-logfile - \
--access-logformat '%t [INFO] %P request_id=%{X-REQUEST-ID}o cf_id=%{X-Amz-Cf-Id}i %r %s %b %Tfs' \
--log-level debug \
--graceful-timeout 180
```

From the logs, we see only this,

```
[2021-01-20 19:05:06 +0000] [25475] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25475
```

What could be the reasons for the reboot?

Comment: ok, so for one of our quart web service, I was facing the same issue. We were on AWS ECS, and my docker container would log the same message that the worker process is restarted.
Later we found out that one of endpoint would generate an async task and this task was quite memory intensive and it would consume all the memory allotted to docker container and would just break in the middle of the operation. We increased memory and it was fixed. Please check you python app code. most probably the issue is there.  Try to isolate your testing for each module/endpoint for finding the issue.

Comment: I have checked the memory and CPU usages. It all seems to be okay.

Comment: I guess you are on your own for this. Even if you share your code and if I run it on mac/linux, I might not face this issue because we have different hardware config. Most probably you would be fixing this issue on your own.  Btw this was the question I asked when I faced similar issue and no one could answer because this is too much specific to your situation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632531/supervisord-sending-sigkill-for-an-asyncio-python-task-after-2-minutes

Comment: The issue could be OOM. Explained clearly in the doc https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/pull/2219/files

Answer (score 1):

As [sp1rs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990200/sp1rs) and [gsb22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6630012/gsb22) are saying, your server is likely to be running out of memory. You say you checked memory usage and it seems to be okay—but are you able to log your Gunicorn worker's maximum usage before it reboots, or are you just checking after it has already rebooted? If you're checking after rebooting, then the worker has already freed up the memory it was using. Note that a Gunicorn worker's memory usage can spike very quickly, in the span of seconds or probably less, and there are many tasks that can cause it to do so. One example is image processing (as it was in my own experience).

As suggested by the [Gunicorn FAQ regarding such silent worker reboots](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/faq.html#why-are-workers-silently-killed), you can use `dmesg` to confirm if you're getting OOM events.